# Does ScyllaDB CQL support the `contains` keyword?

Tags: cql, scylla

Cannot find any information on that in the docs. If it does, what am I doing wrong?

```
cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from id_index limit 1;

 test_keyspace_id
----------------------------------------
 prefix-007

(1 rows)
cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from id_index where test_keyspace_id contains 'prefix';

 test_keyspace_id
---------------

(0 rows)
cqlsh:test_keyspace> describe id_index

CREATE TABLE test_keyspace.id_index (
    test_keyspace_id text PRIMARY KEY
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL","rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Answer (score 1):

> The CONTAINS operator may only be used on collection columns (lists,
>   sets, and maps). In the case of maps, CONTAINS applies to the map
>   values. The CONTAINS KEY operator may only be used on map columns and
>   applies to the map keys.

source: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select

Answer (score 0):

The `CONTAINS` keyword works only with collections. The functionality I was expecting was the one of the `LIKE` keyword